# Restoring Database in PGAdmin

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, import, restore

I am trying to import / restore a PostgreSQL database in pgAdmin on a Mac. I am doing this on a new machine that did not previously have a database on it. I installed and set up pgAdmin on the machine just recently and created a database with no files in it.

Specifically, I am trying to figure out *where* to enter the restore commands found on various forums.

On other forums, I see that others are saying to try the following commands:

```
psql [dbname] < [infile]
```

or

```
pg_restore [option...] [filename]
```

I have never used pgAdmin before so I have no idea where to enter them. I cannot enter anything in the SQL Pane of the database, nor can I enter it as a query (which I tried despite knowing it did not really make any sense >_>).

If it helps, my backup file is on my desktop and is in .dmp format (similar to Oracle). I might be able to get it in a different format if needed but the people I am talking to say that should suffice.

Please let me know if anything comes to mind or if you need any more information. I appreciate any help or pointers anyone has. :)

Comment: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/restore.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked in WINDOWS , I can tell you what i did, you may get the point and do it in MAC .the pg_restore command and others like this i.e pg_dump and others are ther commands which can be run from the pgsql terminal which can be found in the postgres installation folder or may be in the start menu .

From the pgsql terminal following syntax may be used:
    pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U username -d database name -v filename
Commands can also be run from inside the Command Prompt cmd , in WINDOWS i did it like this :

'set path=C:\apache2triad\pgsql\bin 
   C:\apache2triad\pgsql\bin\psql.exe -h localhost -p 5432 -U username-d database_name -f    filename.sql
   pause.. '

For restoring database backup of .backup file from terminal:
   pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U username -d database name -v filename

hope you may get some help here.

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, I am trying to figure out where to enter the restore
>   commands found on various forums.

This is a misunderstanding. pgAdmin is a GUI. You are referring to command line invocations. You do *not* need pgAdmin to run those. Just open a shell and execute the commands. But read [the manual on `pg_restore` and `psql` first](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/reference-client.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can open terminal window here... http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line